# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'data' was called on null.//but the response shows without problem in debug console

Tags: json, flutter

In one part of my program, I send an activation code to the user's email to complete the verification process. In my controller class, I want to get the user ID from the response returned from Jason and store it in a variable with the same name, but it returns null. When I print the response, it shows in the debug console without any problem.

here is my registercontroller class :

```
class RegisterController extends GetxController {
TextEditingController emailTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController activateCodeTextEditingController =
  TextEditingController();
 var email = '';
 var userId = '';
register() async {
 Map<String, dynamic> map = {
  'email': emailTextEditingController.text,
  'command': 'register'
};
var response = await DioService().postMethod(map, ApiConstant.postRegister);
email = emailTextEditingController.text;
userId = response.data['user_id']; // error is here
print(response);
 }

 verify() async {
 Map<String, dynamic> map = {
  'email': email,
  'user_id': userId,// i wanna pass the user id to here
  'code': activateCodeTextEditingController.text,
  'command': 'verify'
};
print(map);
var response = await DioService().postMethod(map, ApiConstant.postRegister);
print(response.data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means no data returned from

```
var response = await DioService().postMethod(map, ApiConstant.postRegister)
```

Trying to do

```
userId = response.data['user_id'];
```

shows that error. Therefore, you should check if there response.data != null before you use it.